# issue in including ASIHTTPRequest into iphone project

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I have an app in which I have to use `ASIHTTPRequest` in order to receive some JSON data from server side.
For this I have done the following:

*included this classes into my project*

[image]

and this

[image]

and also this

[image]

I also included the following frameworks:

[image]

and I get 64 errors looking like this:

[image]

I want to use only this `#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"` but I don't know what classes to import.Please someone tell me what should I include more in order for this to work.Thank you.

Comment: http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/349-How-to-configure-and-use-ASIHttpRequest-with-XCode this is the procedure to add the asihttp.hope this helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include to your project

```
  Reachability.h 

  Reachability.m
```

Add (Project->Edit Project Settings->Build) and find the "Search Paths". In "Header Search Paths" add the following path:

```
/usr/include/libxml2
```

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

See this [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions) You need this to get json Data from server

Answer (score 0):

For Reachability exception, you must include some other files ;)

> From: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions
>
> iPhone projects must also include:
>
> - ASIAuthenticationDialog.h
> - ASIAuthenticationDialog.m
> - Reachability.h (in the External/Reachability folder)
> - Reachability.m (in the External/Reachability folder)